# XConnect IndexWorker Certificate issue

Tags: solr, xconnect

On a developer workstation, all of my xConnect instances are having their  \App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Logs filled with the following error:

> 2018-03-26 22:44:01.661 -04:00 [Error] Failed indexing next set of
>   changes. There will be an attempt to recover from the failure.
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS
>   secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrReader.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Indexer.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexerExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.SingleThreadedIndexer.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.SingleThreadedIndexer.d__4.MoveNext()

I assume this is an issue with Solr certificate. I don't see a step in the Sitecore 9 installation process in which I register the Solr certificate, so wondering how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly download and install the Solr with the most used default configurations with this script by @jermdavis

https://gist.github.com/jermdavis/8d8a79f680505f1074153f02f70b9105

The script does the following things.

- Download the required packages for NSSM and SOLR
- Register Service for SOLR
- Create and Set the Certificates
- Configure the SOLR

There are two thing you will need to update in this script.

`$JREVersion = "1.8.0_151"` to `$JREVersion = "-9.0.1"`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I missed the following step:

> If you created a self-signed certificate, install the self-signed authority certificate for the SSL certificate in the following certificate store: 
>   `Certificates (Local Computer)\Trusted Root Certification Authorities` 
>   Installation Guide, Sections 5.1.3

See also https://medium.com/redhotminute-australia/setting-up-solr-with-ssl-for-sitecore-9-acdf009edd93